# IF and or in expression > cant get it to work

Tags: php, if-statement, operators

Can someone help me with this?

I am trying to show some content which is seperate for US or AU visitors. I am geolocating the IP and also using a PHP session (so that the user can switch countries if required)

```
if (($jsonobj->countryCode == "AU" || $_SESSION['username'] == "AU") && ($jsonobj->countryCode !== "US" || $_SESSION['username'] !== "US"))
{
    echo 'australian content'; 
} 
if (($jsonobj->countryCode == "US" || $_SESSION['username'] == "US") && ($jsonobj->countryCode !== "AU" || $_SESSION['username'] !== "AU")) 
{
    echo 'us content'; 
}
```

I cant get it to work - basically i want the flexibility that either auto by IP to show content or they can manually switch it. Any ideas?

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we have...

```
/**
 * GEO_IP       Session country_code   Result
 *
 * AU           AU                     AU          AU || AU AND
 * AU           US                     US
 * US           US                     US
 * US           AU                     AU          US || AU
 *
 */
if(( $geo_ip_country_code == "AU" || $_SESSION['country_code'] == "AU" ) &&
   ( $geo_ip_country_code == "US" || $_SESSION['country_code'] == "AU" )
) {
    echo 'australian content';
} else {
    echo 'us content';
}
```

But there seems to be a pattern here! Basically the GEO_IP might be used to initially set the Session country code, but it's the session that determines what country they choose to be in so the above can be simplified.

NOTE: If the $_SESSION['country_code'] is already set and I am assuming you do this on the 1st page load with the country that is set, then you don't want to update it.

**A Nicer Solution**

Where you set your Session, you could use something like this...

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['country_code'])){
        $_SESSION['country_code'] = $geo_ip_country_code;
}
```

And then it's just a matter of picking on the current session value

```
$country_code = $_SESSION['country_code'];

switch(strtolower($country_code)){
    case 'au':
        echo "Aussie Content";
        break;
    case 'usa':
        echo "USA Content";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Sorry you can not access this.";
}
```

Comment: This sort of works when you switch on page - but not when you visit the page from an AU or US region (using the geo_ip)

Comment: So how are you setting the Session value, is that being written to on page load from the geo_ip?

Comment: Well, that was my other question - in the PHP header I have:
session_start(); $_SESSION['country'] = $jsonobj->countryCode;

But the problem with that is it resets it everytime - i only want it to run once no matter what page the user enters from

Comment: Actually, I can solve that with if(session_id() == '') {
    session_start();
 $_SESSION['country'] = $jsonobj->countryCode;
}

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition was wrong.
It was verifying both the conditions at once.

This should solve your problem.

```
if ($jsonobj->countryCode == "AU" || $_SESSION['username'] == "AU"){
    echo 'australian content';
} 
if ($jsonobj->countryCode == "US" || $_SESSION['username'] == "US"){
    echo 'us content'; 
}
```

Comment: No as it would display both content if username is AU or countrycode is US

Answer (score 0):

You can search both fields for the word, letters or phrase to decide which to display. If it contains both, it will display both (if you want one or the other, remove the second if and change it to an else)

```
if((bool)strpos(strtolower($jsonobj->countryCode . $_SESSION['username']), 'au')) {
    // Australlian
}

if((bool)strpos(strtolower($jsonobj->countryCode . $_SESSION['username']), 'us')) {
    // American
}
```

If you have multiple, you can create a function to save writing code:

```
function checkDisplay($code) use ($jsonobj) {
    return (bool)strpos(strtolower($jsonobj->countryCode . $_SESSION['username']), $code);
}
```

Then use it like:

```
if(checkDisplay('au')) {
   // Australian
} elseif(checkDisplay('us')) {
   // USA
} else {
   // default or error
}
```